# Using Getx Navigation Go from Homepage-> product page -> Product details page -> homepage without creating new homepage instance

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

If the user clicks on back from homepage, he should go to product details page.

When I am using Get.tonamed(Routes.Home) , Getx is creating a new instance of homepage.

If I remove pages in stack and go back to homepage, I am not able to take user to the details page wien the user presses the back button.

I want to take user to details page when he clicks on back button.

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you want to go back to detailsPage from homePage, you require to stack the homePage above detailsPage , which will create Another instance for obvious reasons.

Comment: Do you want to replace the detaisPage with homeScreen so that he can go back to Products page ?

Comment: can't I go back to homepage and come back to details page when user presses backbutton from homepage?

Comment: No, Please find my below answer to understand the concept of Navigator stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get.ofAll(Home());` to avoid creating new instance of `HomePage` this will remove all the stacked pages in the Navigation Stack

##### Explanation:

When you go from `Home -> Products -> Details -> Home.`

Navigator creates a stack, so that you can go back to the top of the stack when a page is popped

```
| Home     |   Top of the stack 
| Details  |
| Products |
| Home     |
|__________|
```

##### What if i want only one instance of `Home` ?

To access the Home you have to pop all the elements in the stack and reach `Home`

1.Popping Details Screen

```
      _>  Pop Details Page from the stack
|    (     |  
| Details  |
| Products |
| Home     |
|__________|
```

2.Popping Products Screen

```
      _>  Pop Products Page from the stack
|    (     |
| Products |
| Home     |
|__________|
```

Now the stack:

```
|          |
| Home     |  Top of the stack
|__________|
```

##### Is it possible to go back to the `Details Page` now ?

No, you cannot go back to `DetailsPage` because you have popped the `DetailsPage`,`ProductsPage` to reach `Home`

Comment: What if i need to go back to the details page from home?

Comment: You have to create instance of Home() if you have to go back.

Comment: Can you explain more, How can I create an instance? am I not creating instance already when I am navigating to Homepage ?

Comment: On demand of your request, I have edited my post to give you detailed explanation hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pop/Back screens till home page from `Navigation stack` instead of adding it again in navigation stack.In your current code you are again adding home page in Navigation stack from product details page.

so you need to use `offAll`  or `offNamedUntil` avoid new instance of home page you need pop/back screen until home screen.avoid

It will remove all previous pages from navigation stack.

```
Get.offAll(Home()); 

 //  OR. //

Get.offNamedUntil('home', (route) => false); // RouteName
```

For more information checkout this [link](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/route_management.md)

Official package check Readme `Route management` [link](https://pub.dev/packages/get#route-management)

Comment: What if i need to go back to the details page from home?

Comment: You have to again navigate use Get.to() method so detail_page again add in navigation stack and and when you pop from detail page its remove from navigation stack as i mention in my above answer.

Answer (score 0):

On tap in PRODUCTS DETAILS PAGE please do like this:

```
Get.offAll(HomePage());
```